# getVIew has its convertView == null for already existed item when I add new item to listView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to add items in `ListView` dynamicly. When I do that for the first time (so list is empty), `getView()` works pretty fine, convertView is `null` as it supposed to be, so I can use a `ViewHolder` to store references to item's views and bind it to the view through setTag(). But when I add a second item to the list with the data and call `notifyOnDataSetChanged()` really weird behavior has been noticed.

Basically, `notifyOnDataSetChanged()` makes all the visible items to be redrawn, and it starts from the first visible item. The problem is that when the first item (which was already drawn before) is being redrawn, convertView == null, so I need to inflate new view for it and use `findViewById()` to find all the references that I already have found before and stored inside ViewHolder. For the second item I receive convertView that has references to the first one, so I need to find it for the second item. What I want is to get the view that was created before (and has all references inside its ViewHolder) for the first item, and create new one for the second item, i.e. have convertView == null when drawing the item I just added. Is there any way to do that?

EDIT 1: Add new item:

`alarmClocksList.add(new AlarmClock(time, songTitle, weekDaysPanelVisible, weekDaysOn));
    alarmsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

ArrayAdapter:

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AlarmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    ArrayList<AlarmClock> alarmClockArrayList;
    private Context context;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView time;
        TextView songTitle;
        TextView nextRingTime;
        CheckBox repeatCheckBox;
        RelativeLayout repeatPanel;
        WeekDayCheckBox monday;
        WeekDayCheckBox tuesday;
        WeekDayCheckBox wednesday;
        WeekDayCheckBox thursday;
        WeekDayCheckBox friday;
        WeekDayCheckBox saturday;
        WeekDayCheckBox sunday;
    }

    public AlarmsArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AlarmClock> alarmClocks) {
        super(context, -1, alarmClocks);
        alarmClockArrayList = alarmClocks;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_clock_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarmClockTime);
            holder.songTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarmClockSong);
            holder.nextRingTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nextRindDay);
            holder.repeatCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.repeatCheckBox);

            holder.repeatPanel = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.repeatPanel);

            holder.monday = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MO);
            holder.tuesday = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TU);
            holder.wednesday = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.WE);
            holder.thursday = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TH);
            holder.friday = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FR);
            holder.saturday = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SA);
            holder.sunday = (WeekDayCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SU);

            holder.songTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });

            holder.time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimePickerActivity.class);
                    ((FragmentActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.TIME_PICK_REQUEST);
                }
            });

            holder.repeatCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (!isChecked) {
                        holder.repeatPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        holder.repeatPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        AlarmClock alarmClock = alarmClockArrayList.get(position);
        holder.time.setText(alarmClock.time);
        holder.songTitle.setText(alarmClock.songTitle);
        holder.nextRingTime.setText("No data");
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: post some code....

Comment: "Is there any way to do that?" - Nope. You can't control which `View`, if any, is going to be handed to your `getView()` method. Furthermore, it shouldn't matter at all. Inflate a `View` if you need to. Otherwise, just update the one that's given.

Comment: @MikeM. so every time I draw new item (even if I just scroll the list up and down) I have to invoke `findViewByID`?

Comment: You only find your `View`s when `convertView` is null, and you need to inflate. After that, you're using the `ViewHolder`.

Comment: @MikeM, I need to find views not only when I inflate new item, but also in the situation I described in my post, so convertView isn't necessary should be == null. How can I know if I should find all the views again from inside my `getView()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally figured it out! What I needed to do is to set height and width of the `ListView` to `match_parent`. If you use `wrap_content` it forces `ListView` to invoke `getView()` at least 2 times for each item, which was the main cause of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Recyclerview in favor of ListView. With Recyclerview changes from the data array can be published to the GUI with more precision, e.g. `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemInserted` or `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemChanged`.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are reasons why `ListView` can be preferred to `RecyclerView`, e.g. using it with a `CursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is basically optimizing `ListView`s caching solution, which you can't and shouldn't do. Your `ViewHolder` implementation should be agnostic of the way `ListView` caching works. Make sure your code works properly in any case and leave the caching logic to `ListView`.